# How can I put a timer in my python clicking game, and make the circles disappear?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a mouse accuracy game where various circles of different sizes pop up on your screen and it's your job to click them before they disappear in 3 seconds and before the timer runs out in 20 seconds.

I tried using import time with countdown() but it's not working properly. I also don't know how to make the circles have it's own timer and make them disappear. How should I go about doing this? This is what I have so far:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from random import random, randint

CURSOR_SIZE = 20


def my_circle(color):
    radius = randint(10, 50)

    circle = Turtle('circle', visible=False)
    circle.shapesize(radius / CURSOR_SIZE)
    circle.color(color)
    circle.penup()

    while True:
        nx = randint(2 * radius - width // 2, width // 2 - radius * 2)
        ny = randint(2 * radius - height // 2, height // 2 - radius * 2)

        circle.goto(nx, ny)

        for other_radius, other_circle in circles:
            if circle.distance(other_circle) < 2 * max(radius, other_radius):
                break
        else:
            break

    circle.showturtle()

    circle.onclick(lambda x, y, t=circle: t.hideturtle())

    return radius, circle

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor("lightgreen")
screen.title("clicky")

width, height = screen.window_width(), screen.window_height()

circles = []

for _ in range(0, 20):
    rgb = (random(), random(), random())

    circles.append(my_circle("black"))

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't see any timers in your code at all.  This code appears barely changed from when it was posted as [an answer to your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50549622/5771269) except that comments were removed and the circles are now monochrome.  Can you show us your efforts so far adding timers?

Answer (score 1):

Don't give a timer to each circle. Instead, have one overall timer. When a circle is created, store its creation time, perhaps with other information such as the time when it is to be deleted. On each tick of the timer, search through the circles and delete the circles whose time is up. You can speed the search by storing the circle-time-to-destroy information in a priority queue (see the `heapq` module).

This technique of using one timer and searching through lists on each clock tick is standard in GUI programming.